# Upload a NuGet package that is not mine

Tags: nuget, google-code

I have found a dll that is provided via Google Code and I couldn't find it in NuGet. I want this package to be available via a NuGet install, because I want to reuse it in several packages and NuGet seems like the perfect way to do this.

https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-remote/downloads/list

Is it possible for me to generate a nupkg out of these dll's and publish it to NuGet.org? What are the legal limitations to this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of other users that have run into this issue.  It seems like the common solution is to create an "Unofficial" package and reference that for the time being (until Google publishes their library as a NuGet).  Just make sure to very clearly label the package as unofficial.  See [these examples](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=unofficial).

As for the legal ramifications...

Please look through protobuf-remote license and review the distribution and derived works details.  Currently the license is [GNU Lesser GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html).  Sorry, but you'll have to make your own call on if publishing the NuGet package would be permitted under this license.  ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response. For now, I've produced it in my TeamCity private NuGet feed. I will take a look at these unofficial versions when I am going to publish my own package.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you instead create a [local NuGet package source](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds#creating-local-feeds) by pointing to a file share.  This can be local on your computer or on a network file share.

Also, if you don't want to update every workstation, you can [update the NuGet.config file](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file#package-sources) in your project to point to this source and commit that config file in your source control repository for all users to get automatically.  Just note that any change to a NuGet.config file requires you to restart Visual Studio.

And FYI, take a look at how you can [chain multiple NuGet.config files](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file#chaining-multiple-configuration-files).

Comment: I finally want to publish my own package with dependencies to those files. So it will finally be a public package. It will work internally in the company, but what happens when I will publish my own package on nuget.org? I want this library to be a dependency.